# How can I fill multiple similar paths in two separate SVG images?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, vue.js

I am making website where user interacts with svg and fills it with color on click, i managed to make path fill on click, but the issue i have currently is because there is 2 svg and when u click to fill some path on svg1 sometimes svg2 path needs to be filled aswell. I was thinking to add some classes to svg and then check if svg1 path has same class as svg2 path and then fill both paths based on that condition. I was wondering if there is some easier way.Also not all paths should be filled with same color only some, and i dont see any pattern in it. I also thought of adding some metadata but that might complicate things even further. [image: here is what i have currently]
[image: how i want it to work]

```
  mounted() {
    let self = this;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      Array(...document.getElementsByTagName('svg')).forEach((obj) => {
        console.log(obj)
        let children = obj.getElementsByTagName('*')
        console.dir(children)
        let arr = Array(...children);
        arr.forEach(function(item) {
          if (item.classList.contains("frontstich")) {
            item.style.fill = 'black'
          }

          //I WAS THINKING OF ADDING CONDITION MENTIONED ABOVE HERE

          else {
            item.addEventListener('click', function() {
              item.style.fill = self.color;
            })
          }
        });

      })
    })
  }
```

this is my mounted section in vue component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you said, there's no other pattern to tell what should be painted, then you need to specify it yourself.

You can do it with classes or ids and it really isn't very easy to do, specially if you have a big SVG file.

I did something similar a long time ago here https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/xnclb

Notice that for some elements I'm changing gradient stop-color instead of the fill property, but it's basically the same idea. I made an object to map all colors and that allowed me to remove the if statement.

```
 ch[i].attributes['stop-color'].value="#"+colors[names[ncolor]][j];
```

You can also list all your colors in an external CSS and just change the class name of the SVG root element, but you still need to specify what will be painted.

Comment: thank you for your response, i think i will go with classes and then check for each svg1 path if has same class as svg2 path and then based on condition set style of element. I am just worried if this much looping trough arrays might be bad for preformance.

Comment: The link in the answer used to perform at 20 fps when I made it. Now it is almost lagless. I guess browsers got better at svg stuff. But if your file is really big I think you should try the root element CSS method, since it will use less JS